# How to change page after an animation has completed

Tags: jquery, animation

So i want to change the current page with another one after the animation has completed, the problem being i have a step calling a function during the animation, and i really need that function. Currently the animation starts, but doesn't change the page.

```
var a = $("#m").offset().left + 75;
var b = $(window).width()/2;

if (a > b) {
    $("#m").animate({
       left: $(window).width(),
    }, { step: function(val){
        dim();
    }}, function(){
        window.location.href = "video.html";
    });
}else if (a - 150 < b){
    $("#m").animate({
        left: -$(window).width(),
    }, { step: function(val){
        dim();
    }},function(){
        window.location.href = "photo.html";
    });
};
```

Comment: If u give me the code in jsfiddle or plunkr that would help to reslove the issue easily

Comment: @Srikanth Pullela, sorry i had trouble using jsfiddle somehow i couldn't save the code so i've uploaded it to codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNadpr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "complete" function from jquery animate [docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) like

```
$("#m").animate({
             left: $(window).width(),
             },
             { step: function(val){
                          dim();
                     }, 
               complete: function(){
                          window.location.href = "video.html";
               }
             });
```